# Why does Powershell combines array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I use arrays of arrays in a Powershell script, however, sometimes, my array of arrays, actually contains only one array. 
For some reason, Powershell keeps replacing that array containing one array, by just one array. I don't get it, no other scripting / coding language I ever used has done that before.

Example, this is what I do not want:

```
PS C:\Users\> $a = @(@(123,456,789))
PS C:\Users\> $a[0]
123
```

This is what I want:

```
PS C:\Users\> $a = @(@(123,456,789), @())
PS C:\Users\> $a[0]
123
456
789
```

Why do I have to force an extra empty array for Powershell to consider my array of arrays as such when it only contains one array ? This is driving me nuts !

Comment: `$a = ,(123,456,789)`

Comment: Sorry if it sounds stupid, but could you explain this syntax ? Even the microsoft documentation is quite evasive https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx

Comment: @jdel PowerShell is trying to be "helpful" by flattening 1-sized arrays so you don't accidentally end up with nested structures when you don't need them

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a comma as the first item:

```
 $a = @(, @(123,456,789) )
```

The reason for this is that the comma is essentially the array construction parameters. This [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell/) has more information.

Comment: Use of the unary operator `,` will prevent Powershell from unrolling the array.

Answer (score 0):

`@()` operator interpret its content as statements not as expression. Let us put explicit `;`.

```
@(@(123,456,789;);)
```

What do you have here:

1. `123,456,789` — binary comma operator create an array with three elements.
   Result: array `[123,456,789]`.
2. `123,456,789;` — as expression in this statement return collection, PowerShell enumerate this collection and write collection's elements (not collection itself) to the pipeline.
   Result: three elements `123`, `456` and `789` written to the pipeline.
3. `@(123,456,789;)` — array subexpression operator collect all the items written to pipeline as result of invocation of nested statements and create array from them.
   Result: array `[123,456,789]`.
4. `@(123,456,789;);` — as expression in this statement return collection, PowerShell enumerate this collection and write collection's elements (not collection itself) to the pipeline.
   Result: three elements `123`, `456` and `789` written to the pipeline.
5. `@(@(123,456,789;);)` — array subexpression operator collect all the items written to pipeline as result of invocation of nested statements and create array from them.
   Result: array `[123,456,789]`.

So, when you write `@(collection)`, PowerShell return copy of collection, not `collection` wrapped into single element array. If you want to create array with single element, then you should use unary comma operator: `,expression`. This will create single element array regardless of `expression` return collection or not.

Also, when you write `@(a,b,c,etc)`, it is binary comma, who create array. Array subexpression operator just copy that array. But why do you need a copy? Is any reason, why you can not use original array? All you need for not making extra copy is just to omit `@` character: `(a,b,c,etc)`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the principle. I always used the @ for making arrays, because in about_Arrays it is called the array operator.


My problem is i need to build an multidimensional array, that will always behave like such, wether there is one array, or multiple arrays in it.


I played around with the comma operator, but I cannot get this right.

Comment: I feel really stupid not understanding this array thing, but these two examples are confusing me even more:

    PS C:\Users\> $a = ,(123,456),(789)
    PS C:\Users\> foreach ($b in $a[0]) {write-host "--> $b"}
    --> 123 456
    PS C:\Users\> foreach ($b in $a[1]) {write-host "--> $b"}
    --> 789



    PS C:\Users\> $a = ,(123,456)
    PS C:\Users\> foreach ($b in $a[0]) {write-host "--> $b"}
    --> 123
    --> 456
    PS C:\Users\> foreach ($b in $a[1]) {write-host "--> $b"}

Comment: @jdel Important thing here is that unary comma have higher precedence than binary comma. So that `,(123,456),(789)` is the same as `(,(123,456)),(789)`. In JSON notation it will look like `[[[123,456]],789]`. `$a[0]` will be `[[123,456]]`, `$a[0][0]` will be `[123,456]`, `$a[0][0][0]` will be `123`, `$a[0][0][1]` will be `456` and `$a[1]` will be `789`.