# ForEach-Object somehow flattens returned values

Tags: powershell

Let's say I want to read some strings from file, and for each string I want to split it. In the end, I want to get array of arrays of strings. Here is how I try to do it:

```
$toArchive = "./folders.txt"
$folderList = Get-Content $toArchive | ForEach-Object { @($_.split(" ")) }
```

`Get-Content` should return an array of strings, and for each of those strings, I expect to get another array of strings. But instead of that my `folderList` is `Object[]`, as if it was flattened. For example, if my input file looks like this:

```
Docs /home/keddad/Documents/
NotDocs /home/keddad/NotDocuments/
```

I get array of 4 elements:

```
Docs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
/home/keddad/Documents/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
NotDocs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/home/keddad/NotDocuments/
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update: just to clarify, it is definitely array of 4 strings:

```
PS /home/keddad/Documents/tbackup> $toArchive = "./folders.txt"
PS /home/keddad/Documents/tbackup> $folderList = Get-Content $toArchive | ForEach-Object { @($_.split(" ")) }
PS /home/keddad/Documents/tbackup> $folderList.count
4
PS /home/keddad/Documents/tbackup> $folderList
Docs
/home/keddad/Documents/
NotDocs
/home/keddad/NotDocuments/
```

Comment: What does $folderlist.count show?

Comment: @DougMaurer 4, I'll add it to the question

Comment: Powershell loves to “help” users by unrolling collections. Should be able to solve by adding a comma in front of your split. May not even need the parenthesis. 
,$_.Split(“ “) or ,($_.Split(“ “)

Comment: I don't like the comma-operator, IMO it makes the code cryptic. An alternative could be to put the array in a `[PSCustomObject]` like this: `ForEach-Object{ [PSCustomObject]@{ value = $_.split(" ") } }`. PowerShell will never flatten a `[PSCustomObject]`.

Comment: @zett42, there is a verbose, conceptually clear alternative, but it adds overhead: Instead of `, 'foo bar'.Split(" ")` you can use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate 'foo bar'.Split(" ")`.

Comment: @biryulin04, note that `@(...)` isn't an array _constructor_, but a _guarantor_, so to speak: It collects a command's output or an expression's _enumerated_ output in an - always _new_ - `[object[]]` _array_ - even if that output is a _single_ object. Therefore, something like `@(@(1, 2)` does _not_ create a _nested_ array; it is effectively (but inefficiently) the same as `@(1, 2)`; to construct a nested array, use the unary form of `,`: `, (1, 2)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PowerShell flatten arrays automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023626/why-does-powershell-flatten-arrays-automatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the [array construction operator `,`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/array-literals-in-powershell/)

```
(Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") }))
```

Which will render

```
> (Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") })).count
2
```

and, I believe, the structure you like, for example:

```
> (Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") }))[0]
Docs
/home/keddad/Documents/

> (Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") }))[0][0]
Docs

> (Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") }))[0][1]
/home/keddad/Documents/
```

Or visualized holistically as JSON:

```
> (Get-Content .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object ({ ,$_.split(" ") })) | ConvertTo-Json

[
    {
        "value":  [
                      "Docs",
                      "/home/keddad/Documents/"
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "value":  [
                      "NotDocs",
                      "/home/keddad/NotDocuments/"
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s [referal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504),
this question has already been issued several times before:

- [Why does Powershell combines array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36620054)
- [Why does PowerShell flatten arrays automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57023626/1701026)
- [In what conditions does powershell unroll items in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702588)
- [Why does Powershell silently convert a string array with one item to a string](https://superuser.com/q/414650/1085094)
- [Disable collection unrolling in PowerShell with comma trick [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947632/1701026)
- [Why is a leading comma required when creating an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42772083)